# Swift 4: Implementation of a generic protocol with protocol as an associated type

Tags: swift, generics, type-inference, xcode9-beta, swift4

I've experienced a problem during Swift 3.1 to Swift 4 codebase migration.

The problem arrises when you try to implement a generic protocol method that takes a closure with a generic parameter with a protocol as an associated type. It's easier than it sounds :)

The following code works fine in Swift 3.1:

```swift
protocol FooType {
    associatedtype BarType

    func foo(bar: BarType)
    func foo(action: (BarType) -> Void)
}

protocol Bar {}

class Foo: FooType {
    typealias BarType = Bar

    // Compiles in both 3.1 and 4
    func foo(bar: Bar) {
    }

    // ERROR: Candidate has non-matching type (Bar) -> Void
    func foo(action: (Bar) -> Void) {     
    }
}
```

However in Swift 4 compiler gives me an error about class `Foo` not conforming to protocol `FooType` with `foo(action:)` method implementation missing.

By the way Xcode 9 "fix-it" generates the same implementation I have.

The code compiles if I use `BarType` as a parameter type, but it's not good to loose concrete type information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that removing the line

```
typealias BarType = Bar
```

resolves the issue. Which is fair - type inference does its job.

Nevertheless, it should be a legal code and seems like a bug in compiler.

[Reported](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5166) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

We should use the typealias generic variable to feed the type to
associatedType of the protocol. I would go for using the typealias generic variable name in funtion. This makes more sense and legal but I still dont  know why the compiler is not knowing the typealias parameter in closure.

```
class Foo: FooType {
    typealias BarType = Bar


    func foo(bar: BarType) {
     /*Code*/
    }


    func foo(action: (BarType) -> Void) {
      /*Code*/
    }
}
```

Comment: It is legal. However we are loosing clarity in code about the concrete type we are working with in this implementation. Type inference even helps us by not forcing a `typealias` declaration if implementation of all the protocol requirements supply the concrete type it is working with.

You can check [Apple explanation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html) of it in Associated Types section.